# How can you see how much of your alloted storage space you are using in your Exchange mailbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

To be clear, I'm asking this as someone with an Exchange e-mail account, *not* an Exchange administrator.

I've poked around in box Outlook and Outlook Web Access but I don't see where this information is displayed. All I know is that when I *do* run out of space I get an e-mail message telling me my box is full...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://wiki.csuchico.edu/confluence/display/usrvkb/Check+your+Exchange+Account+Size+in+Outlook) is a step by step guide but basically you right click on the mailbox and click properties.

According to [this](http://kb.iu.edu/data/aglh.html) there is a faster way:

- Tools
- Mailbox Cleanup
- View Mailbox Size

Comment: Sweet! This is at least half of what I'm needing, I can now see how much storage I'm using... I still don't see how much space I have left / total space available though. Do I just need to find out from an administrator how much they've allocated my account?

Comment: Correct. The default is normally around the 500MB - 1GB range. Just pop them an e-mail and ask. Or it would be somewhere in the company computer use policy.

Comment: FYI.  The first link "[HERE](https://wiki.csuchico.edu/confluence/display/help/Check+your+Exchange+Account+Size+in+Outlook)" in this solution no longer works.(_I know this is an old thread, but not an old topic as people still want to know._)

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook, right click on your root 'Mailbox' folder and click Properties.

On the 'General' tab, there's a button called 'Folder Size...' - click this button.

The window that then pops up has a 'Server' tab which gives you all the information you need.

*(Note that these instructions were written using Outlook 2007)*

Comment: Still works with Outlook 2016 and is the best answer now

Answer (score 0):

It varies depending upon which Outlook client you're using.

In Outlook for Mac (Office 365 version, which is also Outlook 15), you right-click the Inbox (or other folder you want to inspect), choose Properties, then select the Storage tab.